# Reading line by line in C and storing to array

Tags: c, arrays, input, readfile, getline

[image]

Im trying to read a text file with inputs in the above format. Im able to read each line with this code:

```
FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
...

char * line = NULL;
size_t len = 0;
ssize_t read;
while ((read = getline(&line, &len, file)) != -1)
```

so that "line" is equal to each line in the file and if i output what is read for ex: i get the first output as "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9". How can i store these numbers to a 2d array ?. how can i split at each space and get the number only ?

Comment: Is the numbers of  input always 9x9 ?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Yes, always. its a 9x9.

Comment: In that case it seems easy to use [sscanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Comment: @BLUEPIXY can u suggest a method ? , i did use scanf and it was fine when all the inputs were in one line separated by spaces, but when its 9 lines im not sure how to do that

Comment: I posted a sample using sscanf as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample using `sscanf`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int numbers[9][9];
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    int rows = 0;
    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, file)) != -1){
        int *a = numbers[rows];
        if(9 != sscanf(line, "%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d", a, a+1, a+2,a+3,a+4,a+5,a+6,a+7,a+8)){
            fprintf(stderr, "%s invalid format at input file\n", line);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        if(++rows == 9)
            break;
    }
    fclose(file);
    free(line);
    //check print
    for(int r = 0; r < 9; ++r){
        for(int c = 0; c < 9; ++c)
            printf("%d ", numbers[r][c]);
        puts("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A string is an array, so you just want to copy the contents of the string, character by character to another array, unless the character is not alphanumeric. 
You could do some checks first to see how many alphanumeric characters are in the current string and then grab that amount of memory for your new array.